# Affine cone is a closed set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have seen in the notes of algebraic geometry that if I have a reducible projective algebraic set, i.e given $X$ projective algebraic set, $X=X_1\cup X_2$, $X_i\subsetneqq X$, $X_i$ closed, then $C(X)=C(X_1)\cup C(X_2)$, $C(X_i)\subsetneqq C(X)$ closed. Why $C(X_i)$ is closed?

Comment: If $I$ is a homogenous ideal in $k[T_0,...,T_n]$ it gives a closed set of the projective space of dimension $n$, but you can forget that it is homogenous, and it will correspond to a closed set of the affine space of dimension $n+1$, this is the cone.

Comment: @Ahr that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Comment: Sure, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If $I$ is a homogenous ideal in $k[T_0,...,T_n]$ it gives a closed set of the projective space of dimension $n$, but you can forget that it is homogenous, and it will correspond to a closed set of the affine space of dimension $n+1$, this is the cone.